# Problema de IDE? Python While sys.stdin.read()

Tags: python, while, pycharm

Tentei postar essa minha dúvida em outra flag, mas fecharam o meu tópico alegando que pode sre problema de IDE, então peço ajuda pra tentar resolver esse problema.

```
import sys

def TirarNovaLinhaDeString ():
    print('Coloque a string a seguir e tecle cntrl+D para rodar: ')
    a = sys.stdin.read()
    b = a.replace('\n', ';')
    print(f'Sua nova string é:\n',b)
while True:
    TirarNovaLinhaDeString()
    OpcaoFinalizar = int(input('Se você quer fazer outra transformação digite 0:'))
    if OpcaoFinalizar != 0:
        break
```

Ao rodar o código, por exemplo com a seguinte string para a conversão aparece o seguinte:

```
Coloque a string a seguir e tecle cntrl+D para rodar: 

15,3
12,3
25,3
529
1,7
142,2
```

Coloque a string a seguir e tecle cntrl+D para rodar:

Ele faz a transformação direitinho ao digitar cntrl+D e aparece assim como resultado:

Sua nova string é:
15,3;12,3;25,3;529;1,7;142,2

Mas logo em seguida aparece o seguinte, que é o erro

```
Se você quer fazer outra transformação digite 0:Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "XXXXXXXXX\xxxxxxx", line 10, in <module>
    OpcaoFinalizar = int(input('Se você quer fazer outra transformação digite 0:'))
                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
EOFError: EOF when reading a line


Utilizei o pycharm pra escrever o código e rodá-lo.
```

Comment: O problema aí é a má utilização dos comandos mesmo (ou a não tratativa dos mesmos). Quando você pressiona Ctrl+D no Python o interpretador irá lançar a exceção EOFError. Como você não trata essa exceção, estoura o erro como você apresentou. Você tem duas alternativas: 1) Tratar devidamente a exceção; 2) Ler de outra forma que não precise da exceção

Comment: Já tem muita coisa sobre essa exceção aqui no site: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+EOFError

Comment: Se uma pergunta foi fechada o correto é corrigir os [problemas da original](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/582125/while-true-python-sou-iniciante#comment1017260_582125) e aguardar a reabertura que será avaliada por participantes do site na fila de analises, para checar se sua edição apresentou as devidas/corretas melhorias. Agradecemos se puder separar um tempo para ler os links e orientações, e assim poderá aproveitar melhor o site.